# Django - 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, timezone, django-1.8

Here is my code that I use to make the datetime timezone aware. I tried to use the recommended approach from the Django docs.

```
tradeDay = day.trade_date + timedelta(hours=6)
td1 = pytz.timezone("Europe/London").localize(tradeDay, is_dst=None)
tradeDay = td1.astimezone(pytz.utc)
```

I get the tz_info error. How can I datetime a tz_info attribute?

> USE_TZ = True in settings.py

Answer (score 24):

It looks as though `day.trade_date` is actually a `datetime.date` object rather than a `datetime.datetime` so trying to localize it will cause an error.

Try converting `day.trade_date` to a `datetime.datetime` first using `combine()`. You can then add 6 hours and localize it.

```
# Convert to a datetime first
tradeDate = datetime.combine(day.trade_date, datetime.min.time())

# Now the date can be localized
tradeDay = tradeDate + timedelta(hours=6)
td1 = pytz.timezone("Europe/London").localize(tradeDay, is_dst=None)
tradeDay = td1.astimezone(pytz.utc)
```